# Convert HTML w/embedded Ruby into HAML, Devise

Tags: haml, erb

I am using devise in my application, and need to change the devise HTML into HAML. I am stuck with this statement.

```
<%= error_messages_for resource  %>
```

Can anyone help me convert this to HAML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAML version:

```
= error_messages_for resource
```

Ref: http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#inserting_ruby_

> The equals character is followed by Ruby code. This code is evaluated
>   and the output is inserted into the document. For example:

```
%p   
  = ['hi', 'there', 'reader!'].join " "   
  = "yo"
```

is compiled to:

```
<p>   
  hi there reader!   
  yo 
</p>
```